# Repeat Group Footers in another section

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that shows credit card batches. It's data source contains a bunch of credit card transactions that each have a batch number and card type. The report groups these first by batch number, then by card type. At the end of each card type group, it shows the total amount settled for that card type. After all of the card type groups have been displayed, it shows the batch group footer. Here's an example:

```
Batch 1
 Visa
   Transaction1    $100
   Transaction2    $243

   Visa Total      $343
 AmEx
   Transaction1    $543
   Transaction2    $234
   Transaction3    $49

   Amex Total      $826

   Batch Total     $1169

Batch 2
 ....
```

Now the customer is requesting to see the per card totals above the per batch total. E.G.

```
    Batch 1
 Visa
   Transaction1    $100
   Transaction2    $243

   Visa Total      $343
 AmEx
   Transaction1    $543
   Transaction2    $234
   Transaction3    $49

   Amex Total      $826

   Visa Total      $343
   Amex Total      $826
   Batch Total     $1169

Batch 2
 ....
```

One catch is, I don't know ahead of time which card types there will be so they cannot be hard coded into the report. If there are no Visa transactions, the Visa Total line shouldn't show up or take up any space. If later, a Diners card became an accepted, it should be displayed without editing the report.

It seems silly to have to create a subreport and incur the extra overhead in order to display values that have already been calculated. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for this is i think to use a subreport that would return a summary by batch.